# NodeJS + MongoDB mapping relational data in toJSON()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have three models (collections): Project, User and Category.
The Project Schema looks like this:

```
var ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { // title of the project
      type: String
  },
  _category : {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  }, 
  participants: [ 
      {
          _user: { 
              type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
          }, 
          invitedDate: {
              type: Date
          }
  ]
}
```

The User model has the usual properties: name, email, (hashed) password, address etc.
The Category model has the properties: name, description.

What is an efficient way to retrieve certain properties from User and Category inside the toJSON method of the Project model?
So, for example, when I GET the projects, I don't want the response to return the ObjectID but rather the name and email address of the User, and the name and description of the Category.

Answer (score 0):

You can override toJson method and delete properties which you dont want to return.

Lets take this example. If you dont want to return userId then delete it from definition of toJson method

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var obj = this.toObject()
  delete obj.userId
  return obj
}
```

Just like this, you can change for any schema.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I add properties such as the User's name and email as well as the Category's name and description?

Comment: are these properties exist in different objects?

Comment: Yes in the respective models, I dynamically want to add new properties, just in the toJSON method when I retrieve the project(s) from the server -> { "title": "The Title", "category": { "title": "Business", "Description": "Some Description"}, "participants" : [ {"name": "Joe", "email": "joe@example.com" }, {"name": "Alex", "email": "alex@example.com"} ] }